is accessing the same type through a struct member in a union undefined?
I want to know whether the standard (note not the compilers) say if this is undefined
struct Vec2{int x,y;};

union {
     Vec2 v;
     int x;
} u = {{0,0}}; // v is set

u.v.x; // this is defined
u.x;   // is this undefined? I am accessing the same type but is it?

Note I know that compilers gcc,clang,msvc all treat this as non UB as an extention and I know I could use std::memcpy for type punning.

According to the top voted answer here - "It's actually undefined behaviour to read from a union member that wasn't the last one written to.". Since you wrote to u.v, accessing u.x should be UB according to it.

That u.v.x and u.x happen to have the same type makes no difference.

yea it is undefined look at my own answer to the questiion @wohlstad

@wohlstad that's somewhat outdated answer invalidated by C++11

@Swift-FridayPie could be. It's just what I found in a quick search here on SO. Do you mean that the behavior is defined since C++11 ?

@wohlstad can't use reinterpret_cast in most cases either, and access to memebrs of class-type union membersis covered by common initial sequence rule and by the answer to the designated dupe.

Yes it is undefined how did I know? I tried it in constexpr function.

That proves nothing. Undefined means that compiler can generate working code among other things.  Or intentionally introduce a bug which would stop execution.
Essetially that's either standard or documentaion on platform doesn't impose any limitations or guarantees. It's predetermined by source code somehow, which differs from "undetermined". It's underfined BY documentation, not by an anecdotical fact.

you wrote in your question " I want to know whether the standard (note not the compilers) ". In the answer you refer to what a compiler does and ignore that this is potentially different from what the standard says

I tried on all 3 compilers and they did not compile the constexpr function that means it is undefined behavior it is unlikely the 3 did not follow the standard the answer is full.
